# How to draw this slanted ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn ellipse but how to make it slanted [image] does it need any packages

Comment: Pgfplots is all you need :)

Comment: pgf w/o pgfplots is also adequate (especially if you do not have specific requirements regarding the axes).

Comment: When you say that you have drawn an ellipse, does that mean that you already have some code that produce a diagram with an ellipse? If so, please show us that code, not just your hand drawn sketch.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rotate=30,red] circle(4cm and 2cm);
\draw[rotate=30,green] circle(3cm and 1.5cm);
\draw[rotate=30,gray] circle(2cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I could not upload any Image, perhaps someone else may do this for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Jürgen I never remember it, but I think you need some privileges to make visible uploaded images. So just upload it, your question will show a link and someone with more privileges will edit to public the corresponding image. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the proposal by Ignasi here another possible solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[arrows=->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
 \draw[arrows=->] (0,0) -- (0,8);
 \begin{scope}[shift={(4,4)}]
    \draw[rotate=45,red] (0:4cm and 2cm) arc (0:360:4cm and 2cm)
       node[pos=0.25,font=\scriptsize,sloped,rotate=45,above] {red};
    \draw[rotate=45,green] (0:3cm and 1.5cm) arc (0:360:3cm and 1.5cm)
       node[pos=0.75,font=\scriptsize,sloped,rotate=45,below] {green};
    \draw[rotate=45,gray] (0:2cm and 1cm) arc (0:360:2cm and 1cm)
       node[pos=0.75,font=\scriptsize,sloped,rotate=45,above] {gray};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yes, I eventually found a way to upload a picture!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ellipse`.

I've created a `pic` with 3 `args` (color/x-direction radius/y-direction radius) and a defaul (red/4/2)

*Edit:* I've added the axes like in Jürgen's answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{%
    pics/ellip/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{code={%          
            \draw[rotate=30,#1] (0,0) ellipse (#2cm and #3cm);
    }},
    pics/ellip/.default=red/4/2 % default values
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[arrows=->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \draw[arrows=->] (0,0) -- (0,8);
        \pic at (4,3.5) {ellip};
        \pic at (4,3.5) {ellip=green/3/1.5};
        \pic at (4,3.5) {ellip=gray/2/1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here there is my version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[    
    axis lines=center,
    xticklabels=none,
    yticklabels=none,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    scale=0.8,
]
\end{axis}
\draw[color=gray] (2,2) circle [x radius=1cm, y radius=5mm, rotate=40];
\draw[color=green] (2,2) circle [x radius=1.3cm, y radius=7mm, rotate=40];
\draw[color=red] (2,2) circle [x radius=1.5cm, y radius=9mm, rotate=40];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```